# Unable to type a response in an <input> tag

Tags: html, css, class, input

Goal: I am trying to make a form for users to submit their school schedule

Problem: the first of my input tags will not let me type an input. All the input sections are set up the same accept for their place holder text. they all follow the same pattern and have the same classes applied.

Notes: I know you are able to type in the input field inside of the snippet but it does not work when implemented into my full webpage. Also I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS so excuse the fact that my code is kinda messy. Any constructive criticism is openly accepted.

```css
.form {
  width: 680px;
  height: 870px;
}

.inputConatiner {
  height: 75px;
  width: 680px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.textContainer {
  height: 75px;
  width: 405px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.submitContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.submit {
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 2075%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -75px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: black 0px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

input[type="radio"] {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  border: black 0px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

label[for="A"],
label[for="B"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

fieldset {
  border: black 0px solid;
  padding: 0px;
}

.label {
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans";
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(104, 255, 144);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <head>
  <title>Side Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
<div class="form">
  <form method="post" action="#" name="getStudentInfo">
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">Enter Your Name</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">1A Class</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">2A Class</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">3A Class</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">4A Class</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">A Day Lunch</h1>
      <input type="radio" id="A" name="lunchADay" />
      <label for="A">First Lunch</label>
      <input type="radio" id="B" name="lunchADay" />
      <label for="B">Second Lunch</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">1B Class</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">2B Class</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">3B Class</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">4B Class</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">B Day Lunch</h1>
      <input type="radio" id="A" name="lunchBDay" />
      <label for="A">First Lunch</label>
      <input type="radio" id="B" name="lunchBDay" />
      <label for="B">Second Lunch</label>
    </div>
    <div class="submitContainer">
      <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I can type on the input fields... Check it by running the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have floated the row elements but not cleared them. As a result, the submit button's container element sits at the top of the page, partially overlapping the rows, even though the button itself has been pushed to the bottom (using absolute positioning).

Instead of doing this, you need to first clear the floated elements using **.submitContainer**, and center-align the button within it:

```
.submitContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    /* CLEAR THE FLOATED ROWS */
    clear: both;
    /* CENTER-ALIGN THE CONTENTS OF THIS CONTAINER */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Next, remove the absolute positioning from the **.submit** element itself, as well as the negative margin (since it is now being aligned by its container):

```
.submit {
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* position: absolute; <- REMOVE THIS */
    /* left: 50%; <- REMOVE THIS */
    /* top: 2075%; <- REMOVE THIS */
    /* margin: 0 0 0 -75px; <- REMOVE THIS */
}
```

That will allow the submit container and button to sit below the form without having to push it down.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your wrapper div for submit button is overlapping the first input. Since you've used `float: left` in all your inputs, try and contain all of them in one `div` tag.

Add this to your css

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

And wrap your inputs like

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="getStudentInfo">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="inputConatiner">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="inputConatiner">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="inputConatiner">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="inputConatiner">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="inputConatiner">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="inputConatiner">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="inputConatiner">
            ...
        </div>
    <div class="submitContainer">
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by telling that your css and containers work needs more working...
Your first input tag did not let you type since the "submitcontainer" was overlapping the input tags... I removed the submit Container and positioned the submit button slightly... But I implore you to learn some styling and not dependent on absolute positions...

```
<div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit" />
</div>

.submit {
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -75px;
}
```

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrJGrN